# How to render multiple objects using class based views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I try to render multiple objects using class based views but I get an error.

Here are my codes:

```
class AssociatedList(WizardRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "profile/associated_accounts.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AssociatedList, self).get_context_data(**context)
        all_envelopes = Envelope.objects.filter(
            user=request.user).exclude_unallocate()
        free_limit = account_limit(request, 15, all_envelopes)
        facebook = FacebookProfile.user_profiles(request.user)
        google = GoogleProfile.user_profiles(request.user)
        twitter = TwitterProfile.user_profiles(request.user)

        context.update = ({
            'facebook': facebook,
            'google': google,
            'twitter': twitter,
            'free_limit': free_limit,
        })
        return context
```

**Error:**

```
  local variable 'context' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: @Ngenator I post the error

Comment: As Ngenator points out in the comment on my answer, you've included a reference to 'context' in the statement that defines 'context'. It was a copy and paste error on my part. I've updated my answer, just replace '**context' with '*args, **kwargs', in the first line of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always overridden `get_context_data` by calling `super` at the beginning of the function and then appending context -

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(AssociatedList, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    all_envelopes = Envelope.objects.filter(
        user=self.request.user).exclude_unallocate()
    free_limit = account_limit(self.request, 15, all_envelopes),
    facebook = FacebookProfile.user_profiles(self.request.user),
    google = GoogleProfile.user_profiles(self.request.user),
    twitter = TwitterProfile.user_profiles(self.request.user),

    context.update({
        'facebook': facebook,
        'google': google,
        'twitter': twitter,
        'free_limit': free_limit,
    })
    return context
```

This is the pattern used in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context).

UPDATE

The error you've just added suggests an error with your class. It sounds like you need to define either a `queryset` attribute or a `model` attribute.

The `ListView` class that you're inheriting from requires you to either define the model that the View returns (ie `YourModel.objects.all()`). Or else the specific queryset to be returned (eg `YourModel.objects.filter(your_field=some_variable)`).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. @catherine did this fix the problem?

Comment: Ok here is the new error after adding model, local variable 'context' referenced before assignment

Comment: It's really easy to render one model. But how to render multiple models in one class based view?

Comment: Just inherit from TemplateView instead of ListView and add context using the pattern in my answer.

Comment: The problem causing your latest error is because of a little copy-paste mistake: `context = super(AssociatedList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)` should be used instead of `context = super(AssociatedList, self).get_context_data(**context)`

Comment: I get new error again : local variable 'context' referenced before assignment

Comment: As Ngenator points out I was including a reference to 'context' in the first line of my function. I've updated my code - you shouldn't get that error again.

Comment: another problem again: global name 'request' is not defined

Comment: should be self.request on a class based view. I've updated my code.

Answer (score 2):

Because this is a ListView, you need to tell it what you are going to list with either a `model` or `queryset`. You don't want to use a ListView in this case since you are overriding `get_context_data` so you should probably use a TemplateView or something similar.

Comment: I really don't know about class based views. What will be the correct view I use to render multiple querysets?

Comment: In this case, since you are overriding the `get_context_data` method, a TemplateView would work.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
class AssociatedList(WizardRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = "profile/associated_accounts.html"
    model = Envelope 

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Envelope.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).exclude_unallocate()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AssociatedList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'facebook': FacebookProfile.user_profiles(self.request.user),
            'google': GoogleProfile.user_profiles(self.request.user),
            'twitter': TwitterProfile.user_profiles(self.request.user),
            'free_limit': account_limit(self.request, 15, context['envelope_list']),
        })
        return context
```

You don't need model having queryset, but it is good practice to define it.
In template use object_list or envelope_list instead of all_envelopes and you should be good to go.

P.S. http://ccbv.co.uk/ good source of knowledge about CBV.

Comment: your queryset have also request.user, how would you call the self?

Comment: It gives me again an error. My free_limit call all_envelopes which query is the Envelope that you have put in the get_queryset

Comment: I want also your answer to be the best but I can't check two answer :/